# JPackage only returns SDK Version Number on Java 14

Tags: java, command-line, deployment, java-14, jpackage

I recently ported our Java 11 application to the newly released Java 14 (ZuluJDK). When trying to package our Application with the new JPackage via command line, the only thing that happens, no matter which jpackage-command I'm using, is the following Output:

```
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.jpackage
14
```

An example command (censored some stuff, represented by < > placeholders...):

```
jpackage --type app-image --verbose --input <path> --main-class <class> --main-jar ./<name>.jar --output runtime-image --name "<name>" --version 2.0.0 --vendor "<company>" --icon <icon-path>.ico
```

Can somebody help me what could cause this? The Output of the sdk version does not provide much help.

Comment: I use the Oracle OpenJDK and the jpackage tool just works. The message is normal because the jpackage tool is officially still in incubator state. The message has no effect on the result. Maybe there is something wrong with the Zulu JDK.

Comment: Interesting to see people actually using the tool. Just to clarify, you don't find the image in the output path specified as well? I mean whatever is logged is fine(reads normal), but what else do you expect in the command line?

Comment: Here is a tutorial, which I did together with Dirk Lemmermann, that shows how to use the jpackage tool. Maybe that helps. https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: @Naman No, the output path does not even get created. I did expect some Logging, what went wrong etc.

Comment: @mipa thanks, I found your guide before. I'm just really irritated that basically nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After stripping down argument after argument, I found out that providing the arguments "--version 2.0.0" was causing the issue.

Running

```
jpackage --help
```

provided the following information about version, which is described and behaves differently than I expected:

```
--version
      Print the product version to the output stream and exit
```

So it echoed the JDK Version (14) and, as described, exited. I obviously was looking for --app-version.

Now I get the error that something is wrong with my --output argument, but that is another issue I can hopefully fix on my side. BTW: there is a lot of Logging output once you get it running with the bare minimum arguments required.

Thank you all for your help!